# RealmObject to JSON

Tags: android, json, realm

I am using Realm on Android and I have a RealmObject that I need to serialize to JSON and I am using GSON. The model looks like:

```
@RealmClass
public class User implements RealmModel {

    private String name;
    private RealmList<RealmString> memberships;

    ... (getters and setters omitted) 
}
```

When I read it from the server (using Retrofit and GSON), I write it to the database like:

```
realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user));
```

If I then attempt to serialize the object, it works:

```
String userAsJson = getRealmSafeGson().toJson(test);
```

The Realm safe GSON is pretty much boilerplate from the docs. I put it here to avoid noise: https://gist.github.com/stephenroberts82/0e2cc93fa8983dd86b1f178b7c2c1a88

However, the next time I come and read the model from the database, all the values are null. This is fine, it is the documented lazy evaluation. So I try to do a copy, so GSON can work with it:

```
User copied = realm.copyFromRealm(user);
String userAsJson = getRealmSafeGson().toJson(copied);
```

But this time it doesn't work. It just hangs and eventually crashes due to out of memory.

Comment: tip: if you are not using the return value of `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`, you should use `insertOrUpdate()` instead, it is much faster

Comment: What is `getRealmSafeGson()`? It is not in the gist

Comment: If your User is detached from realm already (with `copyFromRealm()`), you should be able to use a regular gson instance to convert it to json

Comment: It is the new Gson() object on line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because your `User` contains a cyclical reference, and `copyFromRealm()`'s default parameter says that it should try to copy it for as long as possible.

Try something like, `copyFromRealm(user, 1)` or `copyFromRealm(user, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Below code works for me:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {

    RealmResults<User> realmResult=realm.where(User.class).findAll();
    String reslutAsString=new Gson().toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(realmResult));
}
```